# Defining a data structure in Typescript to store this JSON data

Tags: angular, typescript

I am very new to angular / typescript.
I finished my api call and postman returns this data, i now need to somehow represent this in a typescript data structure that would allow me to iterate over these values. The Data represents these classes.

```
public class MainStructure
    {
        public List<ClientStructure> ClientList = new List<ClientStructure>();//Clientlist
    }

    public class ClientStructure
    {
        public List<TreeUser> Userlist = new List<TreeUser>();//users under  client
        public List<AdAccountStructure> AdAccountList = new List<AdAccountStructure>();//ad account under client
    }

    public class AdAccountStructure
    {
        public TreeAdAccount AdAccount = new TreeAdAccount();
        public TreeUser AdAccountUser = new TreeUser();
    }
```

This is the sample result of this.

```
"10X Invest 343": {
        "ClientList": [
            {
                "Userlist": [
                    {
                        "UserId": 732,
                        "UserGUID": "d84a267c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "ClientId": 343,
                        "Name": "Declan ",
                        "Surname": "Hollywood"
                    },
                    {
                        "UserId": 733,
                        "UserGUID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "ClientId": 343,
                        "Name": "Jos",
                        "Surname": "Hilles "
                    },
                    {
                        "UserId": 744,
                        "UserGUID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "ClientId": 343,
                        "Name": "Sam ",
                        "Surname": "Etang"
                    },
                    {
                        "UserId": 745,
                        "UserGUID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "ClientId": 343,
                        "Name": "Lee",
                        "Surname": "Lip"
                    },
                    {
                        "UserId": 752,
                        "UserGUID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "ClientId": 343,
                        "Name": "Cathe",
                        "Surname": "Nei"
                    },
                    {
                        "UserId": 819,
                        "UserGUID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "ClientId": 343,
                        "Name": "Christ",
                        "Surname": "Under"
                    }
                ],
                "AdAccountList": [
                    {
                        "AdAccount": {
                            "AdAccountId": 0,
                            "SocialAccountId": null,
                            "Name": null
                        },
                        "AdAccountUser": {
                            "UserId": 540,
                            "UserGUID": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            "ClientId": 2,
                            "Name": "Van",
                            "Surname": "Clar"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "AdAccount": {
                            "AdAccountId": 882,
                            "SocialAccountId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            "Name": "10X Invest"
                        },
                        "AdAccountUser": {
                            "UserId": 7,
                            "UserGUID": ""xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            "ClientId": 2,
                            "Name": "Geres",
                            "Surname": "Gov"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

So I need to save this data in typescript to enable me to pass it to the front end component

Comment: it's already json format and json can be used in front. to iterate through list clients you just get the list from the json `clients = obj['10X Invest 343']['ClientList']['Userlist'];` and to iterate through you just need to do the following `clients.forEach(obj => {console.log(obj);})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a couple of typescript interfaces that represent your data structure.
and return that interface from your angular http call.

```
interface MyDataStructure {
    ...
}

this.http.get<MyDataStructure>('/api/something');
```

The hard part will be constructing your interfaces to match the backend response.

I suggest reading more about them here
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Will try it out and give you an upvote !

Comment: I found this http://json2ts.com/
It's really handy, i altered the interfaces a little bit, but it looks like its going to work.